# What constitutes a 'well received question'?

Tags: support, badges

A few days ago, I was one question away from getting [Curious](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/122/curious).

I then asked this question: [What actually is Arithmancy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116896/what-actually-is-arithmancy)

This question has (at time of writing) 42 upvotes, has been viewed almost 5000 times and has 4 highly voted answers.

I still do not have the Curious badge.

Is this question not 'well received'? (Yes, I do have a positive question record.)

**What is this question missing that makes it not well received, or is it an error with Stack Exchange?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be that question, but the other one you posted on the same day.

You asked two questions on December 31st (that I can see; I don't know if you have any deleted questions on that day):

- [What actually is Arithmancy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116896/what-actually-is-arithmancy), which was well-received
- [What spells, enchantments and charms do we know were taught in the first year of Hogwart's curriculum?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116900/what-spells-charms-curses-hexes-jinxes-enchantments-and-charms-do-we-know-w), which was closed until recently, and currently has a negative score

Quoting from [the official announcement of the Curious badge family](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) (emphasis mine):

> If you ask at least one well-recieved question in a UTC day and **none of your questions that day are deleted, downvoted, or closed**, you get one more day of credit toward the badge.

So it looks like it's the second question that's holding you back

Comment: oooh I see. So it's based on all the questions that day?

Comment: @MathiasFoster Yes. To maximise your chance of getting the Curious/Inquisitive/Socratic badges, it's best to ask only one question per day.