# Well received question

Tags: support

What exactly is a "well received question" as far as Curious or Inquisitive badge is concerned ? 
I did see a similar **question** being asked,

[What constitutes a 'well received question'?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8087/what-constitutes-a-well-received-question)

but the **answer** there was not so much about the "well received" character but about the fact that there was another question asked on the same day, so it does not answer my question here, which is just the general definition of "well received".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition from the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) is as follows;

> A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0
>
> <sub><sup>[Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)</sup></sub>

Comment: I asked 37 questions, one "bad" one, even if counted triple that's a 0.9 ratio; one is too new to be upvoted (or downvoted) yet, and 35 upvoted. There may be a few pairs on the same day that count as one, not two, but even if I do not have 30 different days yet, I am sure I have at least 25.

Comment: Maybe "duplicate" questions do not count ? But that is a rather **subjective** criterion. Sometimes two questions have the same **answer**, but are still totally different. See for instance
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223991/a-novel-with-sentient-predators-that-can-join-their-minds-telepathically-to-form
My question was about the predators who turned out to be the “Tines”, the only detail I remembered, the question it was supposed to be a duplicate was about “an ancient AI enemy”. These were two entirely independent aspects of “ A Fire Upon the Deep”.

Comment: Some of my “duplicates” are really similar to the previous question (had I known of the older one, I would not have asked them). The one with the Tines is caricatural in the other direction. Most are in between.

Comment: @Alfred Remember that the badges count the number of *days* on which you posted questions. If you posted five well-received questions on one day, that only counts as 1 towards the badge. If you posted five well-received questions and one *not* well-received question on the same day, that doesn't count towards the badge at all.

Comment: I never posted more than 2 on the same day, and then only two or three times maximum. But the problem is the duplicates, which apparently are not counted even if it was impossible to guess from the question itself that the answer was the same. In the case of "A FIre in the Deep" what **I did remember** did not appear **even in allusive form** in the question that mine is considered as a "duplicate" of.  This is not so clear for the other questions, but it is debatable at least for some of them.